# How many points are common to the graphs of the two equations $(x-y+2)(3x+y-4)=0$ and $(x+y-2)(2x-5y+7)=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

How many points are common to the graphs of the two equations $(x-y+2)(3x+y-4)=0$ and $(x+y-2)(2x-5y+7)=0$?

\begin{align*}
  (x-y+2)(3x+y-4) &= 0\tag{1}\\ 
 (x+y-2)(2x-5y+7) &= 0\tag{2}
\end{align*}

In equation $1$, it is not possible for both $x-y+2$ and $3x+y-4$ to be nonzero. Like-wise in equation $2$, it is not possible for both $x+y-2$ and $2x-5y+7$ to be nonzero.
Therefore the LHS of either equation must involve a product of $0$ and some number.
This means there are infinitely many solutions to both equations.

However this doesn't shead any light on which points are common between the two equations. I'm confused. It seems I've made an error in my judgement. What should I reconsider?

Comment: If $(x-y+2)(3x+y-4)=0$, then $x-y+2=0$ or $3x+y-4=0$

Comment: $$AB=0 \text{ and } CD=0 \implies \begin{align*}A& =0 & A&=0 & B&=0 & B&=0\\C&=0 & D&=0 & C&=0 & D&=0\end{align*}$$

Comment: Based  on my comment above and the fact that all equations represent lines such that no two of them are parallel (different slopes), you will have *no more than* 4 points of intersection.

Comment: @AnuragA I don't follow. Are you excluding A and B being 0 simultaneously? Does that apply to C and D? Futhermore, couldn't the equations graph the same line, so that they share every point. Otherwise if they intersect they can only intersect at one point.

Comment: @AnuragA Comparing the equations indivually, and working case-by-case, I found $4$ solutions to equations; $(0,2), (1,1) , (-1,1), (13/17, 29/17)$. Should I take these to be the common points? If the lines from the two equations have different slopes then they will only have one point of intersection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare equations indivually, and work case-by-case.

$$x-y+2=0\implies y=x+2, x+y-2=0\implies y=2-x$$
$$x+2=2-x\implies x=0\to y=2$$

So $(0,2)$ is a solution.

$$3x+y-4=0\implies y=4-3x,\\ x+2=4-3x\implies x=\frac12\to y=\frac52$$

So $(\frac12, \frac52)$ is a solution.

You can do the other two.

Comment: Following the comment on my question (by AnuragA). I let $A=x-y+2, B=3x+y-4, C=x+y-2,D=2x-5y+7$. Working case by case; $A=0, B=0$ gives the soultion $(0,2)$. $B=0, C=0$ gives the soultions $(1,1)$. $A=0, D=0$ gives the soultion $(-1,1)$. And finally $B=0, D=0$ gives the soultion $(13/17,29/17)$

Answer (score 1):

If $x-y+2=0,y=?$

Replace the value of$y$ in terms of $x,$ in the second equation to find

$$0=(x+x+2-2)(3x+x+2-4)=2x(4x-2)$$

$$x=?,?$$

Had there been $n$ factors, we would have $n$ degree equation in $x$

Similarly for $3x+y-4=0\implies y=4-3x$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: $x=1/2,y=5/2$. For the next case it would be $0=AD$ replacing the value of $y$ in terms of $x$ where $y=4−3x$. Is this correct?

Comment: I let $A=x−y+2,B=3x+y−4,C=x+y−2,D=2x−5y+7A$.

Comment: $ (x-(4-3x)+2) (2x-5(4-3x)+7)=0$. This results in an non-linear equations. I only know how to slove linear equtions.